# UIkit dropdown hide and appears again if hide it by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, uikit

Here is the form in dropdown with button that should close this dropdown

```
<div id="kupit" >
    <div class="uk-width-1-1 uk-button-dropdown drop"
         data-uk-dropdown="{pos: 'left-center', mode:'click'}">
        <button href="#" class="uk-button uk-button-primary tm-add-to-cart uk-margin-top uk-width-1-1">Купить в один клик</button>

        <div class="uk-dropdown uk-dropdown-small">
            <p>ПОЖАЛУЙСТА, ОСТАВЬТЕ <br> СВОЙ НОМЕР ТЕЛЕФОНА.</p>
            <p>НАШИ СОТРУДНИКИ СВЯЖУТСЯ<br> С ВАМИ В БЛИЖАЙШЕЕ ВРЕМЯ.</p>
            <form class="uk-form" action="/" method="post">


                <div class="uk-form-row">
                    <input class="uk-width-1-1" name="username" size="18" placeholder="Имя"
                           type="text">
                </div>

                <div class="uk-form-row">
                    <input class="uk-width-1-1" name="phone" size="18" placeholder="Телефон"
                           type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="uk-form-row">
                    <button class="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-width-1-1" value="Войти" name="Submit" type="submit" onclick="popup(this); return false;">ЗАКАЗАТЬ ТОВАР</button>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the code for closing dropdown

```
function popup(here) {
    var test = jQuery(here).closest('.drop');
    UIkit.dropdown(test).hide();
}
```

but when I click on the button dropdown hides and then immediately appears again.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of your mouse is still over the dropdown. The system show the window again beause mouse still there. So if you need to close this dropdown by this button you need to add `uk-dropdown-close` class to this button.

Also you can use this code to add some functionality when dropdown closed

```
jQuery('[data-uk-dropdown]').on('beforehide.uk.dropdown', function () {
// custom code here 
})
```

Comment: Thanks you @progreccor the class `uk-dropdown-close` allows the automatic closing of the dropdownlist when you have selected an item on it.